# Timer in java (delay on actions)

Tags: java, timer, delay, intervals

so I have this small 2d game I just work on. I'm not that good in java but I do understand alot. But I want to make it so when my character fires a bullet he cant fire anymore for 2 seconds. Or whatever delay. I have tried multiple things but it simply wouldn't work with what I was trying to achieve. This is what I use to fire the bullet.

```
    if (Mouse.next() && Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10000);
        Game.bullets.add(new Bullet(new Vector2f(position.x + 25, position.y + 19), new Vector2f(position.x, 0)));
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: An easy way would be to store the time of the last shot in a variable and check every mouse click if the timestamp is older than 2 sec. But there are much more ways to archieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create class variable for storing last shot time
2. Save last shot time in this variable
3. Compare current time and variable's value on shooting event and decide is it permitted to shot again or not.

Something like:

```
if (Mouse.next() && Mouse.isButtonDown(0) && (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastShotTime >= 2000)) {
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10000);
    Game.bullets.add(new Bullet(new Vector2f(position.x + 25, position.y + 19), new Vector2f(position.x, 0)));
    lastShotTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: How do i compare a variable to an other?